# Criteria Builder with predicate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have list of object which I will read from property file and then I will split with pipe symbol and then I need to apply with or clause.
Below is the code.
When I try to apply builder.or the below query is getting genareted, instead of or clause.

```
    String coverageNames = env.getRequiredProperty(AmhiConstants.COVERAGE_NAME);
    String[] coverageName = coverageNames.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
    CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    TypedQuery typedQuery;
    CriteriaQuery<Integer> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Integer.class);
    Root<BenefitCounter> root = criteriaQuery.from(BenefitCounter.class);
    Join<BenefitCounter, BenefitCounterCoverageDetails> benefitCoverageJoin = root
            .join(BenefitCounter_.benefitCoverageDetails);
    Join<BenefitCounterCoverageDetails, CoverageMaster> coveJoin = benefitCoverageJoin
            .join(BenefitCounterCoverageDetails_.coverageType);
    List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();

    conditions.add(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get(BenefitCounter_.isCompleted), 'N')));
    for (String coverage : coverageName) {
        Predicate predicate = builder.like(builder.lower(coveJoin.get(CoverageMaster_.coverageName)),
                AmhiConstants.PERCENTAGE_SYMBOL + coverage + AmhiConstants.PERCENTAGE_SYMBOL);
        conditions.add(conditions.add(builder.or(predicate));

    }

    criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(BenefitCounter_.benefitCounterId))
            .where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));


    criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get(BenefitCounter_.benefitCounterId)));
    criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
    typedQuery = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<Integer> list = typedQuery.getResultList();
    return list;
```

Generated Query:

```
select distinct benefitcou0_.utilization_dtl_id as col_0_0_ from claims.utilization_dtls benefitcou0_ inner join claims.utilization_coverage_dtls benefitcov1_ on benefitcou0_.utilization_dtl_id=benefitcov1_.utilization_dtl_id inner join claims.coverage_master coveragema2_ on benefitcov1_.coverage_id=coveragema2_.coverage_id where (lower(coveragema2_.coverage_name) like ?) and (lower(coveragema2_.coverage_name) like ?) and (lower(coveragema2_.coverage_name) like ?) and (lower(coveragema2_.coverage_name) like ?) and benefitcou0_.is_completed=? order by benefitcou0_.utilization_dtl_id asc
```

Acual Query Needed:

```
select distinct benefitcou0_.utilization_dtl_id as col_0_0_ from claims.utilization_dtls benefitcou0_ inner join claims.utilization_coverage_dtls benefitcov1_ on benefitcou0_.utilization_dtl_id=benefitcov1_.utilization_dtl_id inner join claims.coverage_master coveragema2_ on benefitcov1_.coverage_id=coveragema2_.coverage_id where (lower(coveragema2_.coverage_name) like ?) or (lower(coveragema2_.coverage_name) like ?) or(lower(coveragema2_.coverage_name) like ?) or (lower(coveragema2_.coverage_name) like ?) and benefitcou0_.is_completed=? order by benefitcou0_.utilization_dtl_id asc
```

Comment: 10 days have passed. Did you have the chance to look at the answers? Some users dedicated their time to respond to your question

Answer (score 0):

This is because [`CriteriaQuery<T>.where(Predicate... restrictions)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#where-javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...-), which is the method you are using, according to JavaDoc,

> ...Modify the query to restrict the query result according to the conjunction of the specified restriction predicates

Conjunction means a set of "and" predicates. In order to get the "or", you have to use use [`CriteriaBuilder.or(Predicate... restrictions)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#or-javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...-):

```
Predicate andPredicate = builder.equal(root.get(BenefitCounter_.isCompleted), 'N');
for (String coverage : coverageName) {
    Predicate predicate = builder.like(builder.lower(coveJoin.get(CoverageMaster_.coverageName)),
            AmhiConstants.PERCENTAGE_SYMBOL + coverage + AmhiConstants.PERCENTAGE_SYMBOL);
    conditions.add(predicate);

}
Predicate orPredicate = builder.or(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
Predicate andPredicate = builder.and(andPredicate, orPredicate);

criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(BenefitCounter_.benefitCounterId))
        .where(andPredicate);
```